# No event catch during button pressed [ QT ]

Tags: c++, qt

I have to make a virtual keyboard.

So I created few `QPushButton`s, but if I click on one, and move to release on another, then the other button doesn't receive any mouse event.

I to override `enterEvent(QEvent *)` and `leaveEvent(QEvent *)`, but without success when I have clicked on another button.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1):

In QAbstractButton code:

```
void QAbstractButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    Q_D(QAbstractButton);
    if (e->button() != Qt::LeftButton) {
        e->ignore();
        return;
    }
    if (hitButton(e->pos())) {
        setDown(true);
        d->pressed = true;
        repaint(); //flush paint event before invoking potentially expensive operation
        QApplication::flush();
        d->emitPressed();
        e->accept();
    } else {
        e->ignore();
    }
}
```

When mousePressEvent triggers, QAbstractButton calls `setDown(true)` and QAbstractButtonPrivate ( `Q_D(QAbstractButton)` ) calls `d->emitPressed()`. After that, others buttons will not receive any events, they are already handled in the active button.

You can see in `mouseReleaseEvent`

```
void QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    Q_D(QAbstractButton);
    d->pressed = false;

    if (e->button() != Qt::LeftButton) {
        e->ignore();
        return;
    }

    if (!d->down) {
        // refresh is required by QMacStyle to resume the default button animation
        d->refresh();
        e->ignore();
        return;
    }

    if (hitButton(e->pos())) {
        d->repeatTimer.stop();
        d->click();
        e->accept();
    } else {
        setDown(false);
        e->ignore();
    }
}
```

It also checks state `d->down`. And if mouse hits that button, it will call `d->click();` emit click event. If mouse does not hit button, it call `setDown(false);` to reset state.

I suggest to inherit virtual button from QWidget for easier handle mouse events.